# Finding a special natural number for a fixed natural number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n$ be a fixed natural number. How can we find a natural
number $i$ such that $in-1$ divides $i^2n.$

Comment: So..... you want $i^2n\equiv 0\pmod{in-1}$... in what context does this question arise?

Comment: **Hint** $\ in-1\,$ is  coprime to $i,n\,$ so coprime to $\,i^2 n\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $p$ is a prime dividing both $in-1$ and $i^2n$. Then $p$ divides $in$, hence $p$ divides $in-(in-1)=1$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore $in-1$ and $i^2n$ are coprime, and therefore $in-1$ divides $i^2n$ only when $in-1=1$.

Comment: So, unless $n=1$ or $n=2$, this is impossible?

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs: that's right.